# put files under version control - how to untrack them and ignore

Tags: git

I've added files under version control. Now I need to remove them from version control and ignore in my project. Is it enough to just put those files inside `.gitignore` or I have to delete them first? What's the correct procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the file from git while leaving it in your working directory, you need to `git rm --cached` the file, then commit.  If you just add the file to `.gitignore`, the current version of the file will remain in git.

Comment: Thanks, can I specify the list of files (files in one folder) with `git rm --cached` ?

Comment: yes, e.g. `git rm --cached readme.txt` for file or `git rm --cached log/\*.log` for files in directory using wildcards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `.gitignore` is it enough (if you just want do not track this files)
But if you want delete it from your project and from git - delete files

Thats all ;)